# Collision Response: Should stop object, but does slow down object. I dont understand why

Tags: java, collision, slick2d

I am building a simple collision system for a plattformer. Now when i am looking at the code, i think like: Yep, that obviously HAS to work. But when i run the application, instead of stopping the object thats colliding, it only slows it down, so that it still can move right through other objects.

What I did in short: AABB-Collision detection (probably works), resetting objects to their last place before collision (seems to not work(?)), setting the velocity of the colliding direction to zero (doesnt work).

I would be very grateful if someone could take a look at it or give me some advice for achieving proper collision detection. (I already read like 20 tutorials but obviously cant figure it out)

Here is my code (Java): (all that is in a regular game-loop-method thats iterated)

```
//Starting with a regular AABB-Collision, detection seems to work so far
if(creature1.x+creature1.width >= creature2.x
    && creature1.x <= creature2.x+creature2.width
    && creature1.y+creature1.height >= creature2.y
    && creature1.y <= creature2.y + creature2.height)
{

    //Setting the position back to the moment before collision, doesnt work for unknown reasons.
    creature1.x=creature1.lastX;
    creature1.y=creature1.lastY;

    //checking which side collides and setting the corresponding velocity to 0. Checking for sides by comparing the distance between the center of the hitting objects edge and the center of the targets AABB. 
//Basically much pythagoras.

    int distRight= (int) Math.sqrt((creature1.lastX+creature1.width   -    creature2.lastX+creature2.width/2) *(creature1.lastX+creature1.width-creature2.lastX+creature2.width/2)    +    (creature1.lastY+creature1.height/2-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2)*(creature1.lastY+creature1.height/2-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2));
    int distLeft=  (int) Math.sqrt((creature1.lastX   -    creature2.x+creature2.width/2) *creature1.lastX-creature2.lastX+creature2.width/2)    +    (creature1.lastY+creature1.height/2-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2)*(creature1.lastY+creature1.height/2-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2));
    int distTop = (int) Math.sqrt((creature1.lastX+creature1.width/2   -    creature2.lastX+creature2.width/2) *(creature1.lastX+creature1.width/2-creature2.lastX+creature2.width/2)    +    (creature1.lastY-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2)*(creature1.lastY-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2));
    int distBot = (int) Math.sqrt((creature1.lastX+creature1.width/2   -    creature2.lastX+creature2.width/2) *(creature1.lastX+creature1.width/2-creature2.lastX+creature2.width/2)    +    (creature1.lastY+creature1.height-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2)*(creature1.lastY+creature1.height-creature2.lastY+creature2.height/2));

    if(distRight<distLeft && distRight<distTop &&distRight<distBot){
        creature1.velocityX=0;
    }
    else if (distLeft<distRight && distLeft<distTop && distLeft<distBot){
        creature1.velocityX=0;
    }
    else if (distTop<distBot &&distTop<distRight && distTop<distLeft){
        creature1.velocityY=0;
    }
    else if (distBot<distTop &&distBot<distRight && distBot<distLeft){
        creature1.velocityY=0;
    }
}
else{ 
}
}

                    //Setting up "last"-Positions
creature1.lastX=creature1.x;
creature1.lastY=creature1.y;

collisionCreatures.get(c).x+=collisionCreatures.get(c).velocityX;
collisionCreatures.get(c).y+=collisionCreatures.get(c).velocityY;

}}
```

Comment: so which part exactly doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: the response part: after detecting a collision i want the colliding object to reset its position. If that would be the case, the object could never penetrate the target. Since it does, that part does not seem to work. Also the part where i check for the shortest edge does not work, because none of the velocity values are set to zero.